# Finding the coordinates of congruent squares (side length d) to approximate the surface of a sphere (radius r)?

Tags: geometry, approximation, spheres, conformal-geometry, spherical-geometry

> I have a sphere and I want to *approximate* it's surface with congruent, adjacent
>   and not overlapping squares whose corner points should sit on the
>   sphere's surface.
>
> Sphere's radius: r
>  Squares' side length: d
>  Coordinate system:
>   x to the right, y upwards, z to the depth
>  Position of sphere's
>   center: (0,0,0)
>  Position of center of "first" square should be on
>   the negative part of the z-axis

How to find the coordinates?

Background: I want to separate the very big "planet" file for the openstreet map data into small separate files. What I saw so far of existing solutions doesn't fit my purpose or setting - simple, fast and low cost with an accuary only to the same detail one would need looking at a classical city map or highway map.

> Example values: 
> r = 6,378,137 m (which gives a circumference of about 
>   40,075,017 m) 
>  d = should be best match to 1000 m

Comment: The only way to form a closed surface out of congruent squares is the cube. You need to relax those conditions to have any hope at all.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Indeed, I came to the same conclusion. I still prefer congruent sqaures, but they could overlap. I will edit the question, just don't have time currently to make a proper wording.